# templateInstance.model in Polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

In [polymer 0.5](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding.html#event-handling-and-data-binding), `this.templateInstance.model` provided a way of accessing properties defined in the scope of an encompassing `is="auto-binding"` (or any other) template of `this` element.

Now, in polymer 1.0 what is the equivalent way of accessing properties of the encompassing `is="dom-bind"` (or any other) template?

**EDIT:**

For example, in the snippet below both elements `<my-el-a>` and `<my-el-b>` intend to set values to the encompassing `<template is="dom-bind">`'s `counterA` and `counterB` properties respectively.

`<my-el-b>` does so succesfully via a reflective property `counter` (`notify:true`).

`<my-el-a>` intends to do so via the "parent"/`templateInstance.model` but fails. This **used to work** in Polymer 0.5. How can I get this to work in Polymer 1.0? In other words, what's the equivalent for `templateInstance.model`?

```html
<script>
  ! function() {
    var counterA = 0;
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-el-a',
      ready: function() {
        counterA += 1;
        this.instanceTemplate.model.counterA = counterA; //used to work in Polymer 0.5
      }
    })
  }();
</script>

<script>
  ! function() {
    var counterB = 0;
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-el-b',
      properties: {
        counter: {
          value: 0,
          type: Number,
          notify: true
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        counterB += 1;
        this.counter = counterB;
        console.log(this);
      }
    })
  }();
</script>

<template is="dom-bind">
  <div>CounterA: <span>{{counterA}}</span>
  </div>
  <div>CounterB: <span>{{counterB}}</span>
  </div>
  <my-el-a></my-el-a>
  <my-el-b counter="{{counterB}}"></my-el-b>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not yet documented but evident from the [source code](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/279d381a27ef61f026731d811349f60c289d5569/src/lib/template/templatizer.html#L85-L87) that I can access the template instance properties from `dataHost` defined as:

```
var dataHost = (this.dataHost && this.dataHost._rootDataHost) || this.dataHost;
```

In the context of the example given in the question, I can replace:

```
this.instanceTemplate.model.counterA = counterA;
```

with:

```
var dataHost = (this.dataHost && this.dataHost._rootDataHost) || this.dataHost;
dataHost.counterA = counterA;
```

In other words, `templateInstance.model` is replaced with `dataHost`.

Comment: I discovered `dataHost` just a moment ago, and it suits my needs perfectly. What are peoples thoughts on using such undocumented features, could this be risky?

Answer (score 0):

The properties defined on a `<template is="dom-bind">` context are available directly on the template element itself.

What you are asking for is an anti-pattern, you should use the binding system.

If it was clearer why you wanted to avoid the binding system, maybe another answer would emerge.

Fwiw, there is no guarantee that something that used to work in 0.5 will have an analog in 1.0. The data system was completely replaced.

Comment: How can I access `is=dom-bind`'s properties from within a child polymer element?

Comment: You need to be more specific. How you access one element from another depends on where each element is in the tree. Also, whenever possible use binding instead of getting node references. For example: `<template is="dom-bind"><paper-spinner active="{{active}}"></paper-spinner></template>` ... now paper-spinner.active is bound to template.active, and I never had to get a reference to the template.

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events

Although this isn't clear from the docs, I believe `event.model` may be added to events fired from inside the `dom-bind` as well. The `modelForElement`, `itemForElement`, and `indexForElement` methods are only available on `dom-repeat`, however.

I've only used those on a template repeater in the past, but if you have a good use case for having them on an autobinding template, you might want to open up a feature request.

Comment: Thanks @DocDue. Even though my reference related to events, my question about `templateInstance` was more general as in the example I added.

Answer (score 0):

Just assigning any property and binding to it should work, like done in the `dom-bind` tests 
- https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/3b0d10b4da804703d493da7bd0b5c22fc6f7b173/test/unit/dom-bind.html#L30
- https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/3b0d10b4da804703d493da7bd0b5c22fc6f7b173/test/unit/dom-bind.html#L65
assign and bind to `value` and `notifyingvalue`.

[A working example at JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/coseyonuhu/1/edit?html,css,console,output)